# How to redirect part of output of git subtree push

Tags: bash, git, parsing, gitlab, gitlab-ci

`git subtree push ...` produces a lot of output. Although it is ok, using them on gitlab-ci is a nightmare.

I find it awful because the outputs are displayed line by line:

```
git push using:  git@gitlab.xxx.com:micro/service.git feature/ci
1/207 (0)
2/207 (1)
3/207 (2)
4/207 (3)
5/207 (4)
6/207 (5)
7/207 (6)
8/207 (7)
...    
Everything up-to-date
```

How can I hide `1/207 (0)` without hiding the rest?

**I tried**

1. with the `-q` parameter, doesn't work
2. to pipe the output to a regex to "hide" the annoying lines:
   `$ git subtree push ... | while IFS= read -r line; do if [[ "$line" =~ [0-9]+/[0-9]+ ]];then : ; else echo "$line"; fi done` doesn't work
3. ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a grep to find and discard the line you don't want. But this is very specific to that query. Are you sure you don't want to hide some line class instead of just a string?

For your specific question, try

```
git subtree push ... | grep -v "1/207 (0)"
```

UPDATE:

Given the clarification, just adapt the search term and use regular expressions:

```
git subtree push ... | grep -v -e '[0-9]+/[0-9]+'
```

Comment: 1/107 (0) was just an example. I want to remove anything having this pattern: =~  [0-9]+/[0-9]+